# USB webcam showing green screen

Tags: usb, webcam, driver

I am trying to get my usb webcam working with pi, but apparently there is a problem with coding or driver, as the camera output is showing only green screen with some crazy pixels at the top (as the image shows).

[image]

Ive tried motion and fswebcam and both are showing exactly the same thing.

The camera I am using is a cheap camera I bought on ebay, [this](http://i00.i.aliimg.com/img/pb/209/275/623/623275209_277.jpg).

Some information from the pi about the camera:

> **ls /dev/video***
>
> /dev/video0

.

> **lsusb**
>
> Bus 001 Device 007: ID 090c:037b Silicon Motion, Inc. - Taiwan (formerly Feiya Technology Corp.) Silicon Motion Camera

.

> **v4l2-ctl --list-formats**
>
> ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
>
> Index       : 0
>
> Type        : Video Capture
>
> Pixel Format: 'YUYV'
>
> Name        : YUV 4:2:2 (YUYV)

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: I had the same problem with my Microsoft vx500, in my rpi 3 B, I changed my OS to ubuntu Mate and it get fixed.. I hope that helps..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem by taking the webcam out of the USB hub and putting it directly into Pi's USB port. That was easier than expected.

Answer (score -1):

you should have bought a well-known brand, like Logitech or something. these are more likely to have working drivers, larger community of users and better support. cheap chinese cameras usually have win-only drivers and only basic features, thus should be avoided if possible.

for the current camera, I'd advise to try to use it with a win-PC, if it works, then Linux-PC, if is works -- try to find the drivers and probably recompile from the source (since RasPi has different CPU from your desktop PC).